# Two questions about Sonoluminescence in water: Does it produce Cherenkov radiation? Could be done with a laser beam instead of sound?

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics, laser, bubbles, cherenkov-radiation

Two questions about Sonoluminescence in water:

1. Does Sonoluminescence in water produce Cherenkov radiation when the bubble is collapsing?
2. Could be made the same collapsing bubbles but instead of using sound, make them through focusing a High Intensity Laser Beam in the water tank?

If both experiments have been already done please share the references. Thanks.

Comment: A search term for the second question might be "laser-induced cavitation." No idea whether it's a thing or not, though.

Comment: Does laser-induced catastrophic self-focussing in liquids count? Yariv, in his Quantum Electronics book (A. Yariv, Quantum Electronics, 2nd Ed., John Wiley & Sons, NY, 1975, pp. 498-505) discusses self-focussing in carbon disulfide. I tried the experiment, using a nitrogen laser (about 1 mJ per pulse at 337 nm) gently focussed on a fused silica cuvette filled with carbon disulfide. The result was a small hole punched in the cuvette, a small white light and a nicely audible sound produced with every laser pulse. Nice photoacoustic effect.